# HikariCP shows unavailable connections while database has no sessions running - how to find the cause?

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have an application running with Spring-Boot using Spring's default Hikari Connection Pool.
Recently the server started having issues with unavailable connections:

```
DEBUG HikariPool     (411) - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=20, active=20, idle=0, waiting=3)
DEBUG HikariPool     (411) - HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=20, active=20, idle=0, waiting=2)
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper(137) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper(142) - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30005ms.
```

Since it is a shared database, first I wasn't sure if it is a problem in my application. But after restarting the application the connection was fine again, so I now need to find the cause. The error occurs only on the productive system which is used all around the clock with many actions per minute. I tried to figure out what was causing rising active connections in Hikari by scanning the logs for specific statements executed before the rising connection - but there were always different or unclear actions.

So then we executed a script on the database to return all active connections (gv$session). The result returned not a single active session even though the Hikari Logs showed active connections at the same time. Can anybody tell me what this means and/or has a clue where to find the root cause of this issue?

I use Spring Boot v2.1.4.
These are my hikari settings: (default with spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20)

```
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1020) - HikariPool-1 - configuration:
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - allowPoolSuspension.............false
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - autoCommit......................true
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - catalog.........................none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - connectionInitSql...............none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - connectionTestQuery.............none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - connectionTimeout...............30000
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - dataSource......................none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - dataSourceClassName.............none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - dataSourceJNDI..................none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - driverClassName................."oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - healthCheckProperties...........{}
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - healthCheckRegistry.............none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - idleTimeout.....................600000
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - initializationFailTimeout.......1
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - isolateInternalQueries..........false
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:oracle:thin:<masked>
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - leakDetectionThreshold..........0
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - maxLifetime.....................1800000
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - maximumPoolSize.................20
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - metricRegistry..................none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - metricsTrackerFactory...........none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - minimumIdle.....................20
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - password........................<masked>
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - readOnly........................false
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - registerMbeans..................false
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - scheduledExecutor...............none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - schema..........................none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - threadFactory...................internal
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - transactionIsolation............default
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - username........................none
DEBUG HikariConfig   (1052) - validationTimeout...............5000
```

Comment: Given your pool stats seem to indicate a maximum of 10 connections, are you sure it is the same pool (which has min/max size of 20)? Or could your database server disallow the user to have more than 10 connections, or is there an overall maximum that is reached preventing your application from allocating more connections?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel oh you are right, I increased the pool size of Hikari (spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20) as a temporary solution, but obviously it changed nothing except the connections being unavailable a while later.

Comment: That sounds like your application isn't returning connections. Make sure your code **closes** connections when it finishes a unit of work. Closing the connection is what returns it to the pool.

Comment: yea that sounds right, but I checked every statement, all transactions use JDBC Repositories which should be transactional by default, all usages of EntityManager have the PersistentContext annotation. I thought Transactional is enough to make sure it closes the connections in the end?

Comment: It normally should, unless you're doing non-standard things.

Comment: non-standard like what? I might have a few statements that can take a little bit longer, but no matter how many times I start them, they seem to have no effect on the active connections. The application is not that small, so I don't really know where to search anymore.

Comment: Non-standard as in obtaining connections directly yourself, but without seeing the actual code, this is not something that is easy to debug, and I'm not sure Stack Overflow is a suitable venue for this. Consider using a profiler (e.g. YourKit) to see if you can find connection leaks.

Comment: Make sure to check the database alert log. Have you reached the number of processes limit? init param: processes

Answer (score 0):

Enable `leakDetectionThreshold=<max query time in ms>` (documented [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)).

It logs connections not returned to the pool within the time specified.